# Как реализовать событие при клике на одном из элементов с одинаковыми классами

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется несколько div c class='card'.
как реализовать в js, чтобы при нажатии на одном из элементов происходило событие какое-либо?
Вот ниже моя реализация которая не работает:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('card').onclick = function (){
   alert('asfd');
}
```

Div создается следующим образом:

```
var div=document.createElement('div');    
    div.classList='card'; 


for(i=1;i<4; i++){
    for(j=1;j<7;j++){
        var cardClone = div.cloneNode(true);        
        cardClone.setAttribute('grid-column',j);
        cardClone.setAttribute('grid-row',i);
        place.appendChild(cardClone);

    }
```

Comment: А вам принципиально использовать чистый js?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос: нужно, чтобы на каждой копии висел Listener, или только на одном блоке из всех клонов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByClassName() выводит массив, для событий можно использовать так же и addEventListener(event, callback)

```js
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('card').length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('card')[i].onclick = function (){
    alert('asfd');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
place.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if (e.target.classList.contains("card")) {
    alert("asfdf");
  }
});
```